# Question about circles In $R^2$

Tags: geometry

Given a circle C in $R^2$ Defined by three points $(a,b,c)$, And given a point $w$ Inside C, Can I say for sure the circle defined by $(a,b,w)$/$(a,c,w)$/$(c,b,w)$ Will have smaller diameter then C?

It sounds true to me But Im not $100$% sure.

No need a formal proof, just a convincing explanation will be nice.

thanks.

Comment: I don't think so. Say $a,b,c$ are the points of an equilateral triangle and put $w$ very close to one of the edges, say $a,b$. Then $a,w,b$ will be large and can be made larger than the original circle.

Comment: No it is not true. Take $\triangle ABC$ with $\angle ACB = 90^\circ$ then the radius of the circle passing through points $A, B$ and $C$ is $c/2$. Now let's take a point $P$ closer to $AB$ such that $\angle APB = 150^\circ$. Then the radius of the circle passing through $A, P$ and $B$ is $c$, double the radius of the circle passing through $A, B$ and $C$.

Comment: Definitely not true.  Consider the line $\overline{ab}$.  If we find a point $w$ in the circle very very close to that line (or, god forbid, *on* that line) then the circle formed by $a,b,w$ can have a radius as large as we want..... Maybe I don't know what you mean by the circle defined by "$(a,b,w)/(a,c,w)/(b,c,w)$ is that *one* circle (how?) or three circles?  Are you asking if *all* of them have smaller diameters or are you asking if at least one will have a smaller diameter.  I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Actually, I'm having a hard time seeing why it would even seem true.  To have $(a,b,w)$ smaller than $(a,b,c)$ we must putt $w$ "further away" from $\overline{ab}$ than the distance $\overline{ab}$ is to "the point of the circle" above it.  And at any rate you can easily have $c$ in $(a,b,w)$ and $w$ in $(a,b,c)$.  They can't *both* be smaller than each other.